# Verifying an integral identity related to asymptotic homogenization of an elliptic partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

**Background**

I'm reading Hornung (1997)'s Homogenization and porous media, pg 3:

> We study a family of [1D] problems, indexed by the scale parameter
>    $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$, namely,   \begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}\left(
>  a^\epsilon(x)\frac{du^\epsilon}{dx}\right)=0 \text{ in (0,1)}, \\
>  u^\epsilon(x)=0 \text{ at } x=0 \\ u^\epsilon(x)=1 \text{ at } x=1 
>  \end{align}
>
> where we make the assumption that the functions $a^\epsilon(.)$ are
>   given in the form $a^\epsilon(x)=a(\frac{x}{\epsilon}$ with a fixed
>   periodic function $a(.)$ having periodicity of length $1$.  The
>   meaning of this is that the functions $a^\epsilon(.)$ are oscillatory
>   with increasing frequencies for $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.  [In this
>   case], we get
>
> \begin{align} u^\epsilon(x)=\frac{\int_0^x \frac{dt}{a^\epsilon(t)}
>  }{\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{a^\epsilon(t)}} =
>  \frac{\int_0^{nx}\frac{dy}{a(y)}}{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)} }
>  \end{align}

I thoroughly understand how the author obtained this result.  However...

**My Question**

The author claims claims that

\begin{align}
\frac{\int_0^{nx}\frac{dy}{a(y)}}{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)} }
=
x + \frac{ \int_0^{nx} \left(\frac{1}{a(y)} -1 \right) dy }{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}}
\end{align}

However, I cannot seem to verify this identity.  I've tried simplifying the RHS, in which case I obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
x + \frac{ \int_0^{nx} \left(\frac{1}{a(y)} -1 \right) dy }{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}} & = & x + \frac{ \int_0^{nx} \frac{1}{a(y)} dy }{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}} - \frac{ \int_0^{nx} 1 dy }{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}} \\
& = & x + \frac{ \int_0^{nx} \frac{1}{a(y)} dy }{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}} - \frac{ nx}{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}}
\end{eqnarray}

I notice that the middle term in this last expression

$$\frac{ \int_0^{nx} \frac{1}{a(y)} dy }{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}}$$

is exactly equal to what I wanted to verify.  However, the two other terms $x$ and $-\frac{ nx}{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}}$ do not necessarily cancel.

I'm getting the feeling that either I'm missing something totally obvious or that this so-called 'identity' is a typo (I doubt the latter).

Any help verifying this identity would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a typo. Maybe they meant \begin{align}
\frac{\int_0^{nx}\frac{dy}{a(y)}}{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)} }
=
x + \frac{ \int_0^{nx} \left(\frac{1}{a(y)} -\frac 1 {a(y/x)} \right) dy }{\int_0^n \frac{dy}{a(y)}}
\end{align}